# Write SQL generated by Entity Framework into an existing text file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have problem in writing the SQL generated by Entity Framework to an existing text file.

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext())
{
   context.Database.Log = s => Write(s);
   var data = context.Customers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).ToList();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

The `Write` method is like this:

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C: \Users\DEVELOPMENT\Downloads\mytxt.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    streamWriter.Write(s);
}
```

The problem is that, not everything is being written in this text file, when I use something like this:

```
using (var context = new CustomerContext())
{
   context.Database.Log = s => MessageBox.Show(s);
   var data = context.Customers.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).ToList();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

I see more data sequently in the messageboxes (several message boxes are opening, each containing fragment of the whole data. When I press ok, another fragment in another message box is shown and so on..)

What can I do?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `FileMode.Append` so as not to overwrite the file contents every time?

Comment: thank you, it works, I am new to working in files, so...